# mysql how do you place an alias on a derived table

Tags: mysql, left-join, alias

I have the following query

```
SELECT * FROM(
    (select * from `responses` a  order by id, exam, question)
       left JOIN
          (select max(exam) as maxexam from responses b )
              on a.exam <= b.maxexam
              and id > 2) c
```

I get the following error message

```
Every derived table must have its own alias
```

Comment: Do not [delete & repost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78017593/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-aliasalias-need) questions. Especially when it subverts site protocols like closure. Please act on feedback. [Help]

Comment: It has all the same problems and is another small dump of almost exactly the same bad code. Act on its feedback & the [help]. [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using join condition `on a.exam <= b.maxexam and id > 2` then uou need to give alias `a` and `b` to the two subqueries:

```sql
SELECT * FROM
    /* alias a applied to first subquery: */
    (select * from `responses`  order by id, exam, question) a
    left JOIN
    /* alias b applied to second subquery: */
    (select max(exam) as maxexam from responses) b
    on a.exam <= b.maxexam and id > 2
;
```